# Rails 3 Attendance Form with Multiple days per week and Multiple children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to create a form that will allow you to enter or update the time for attendance on a daily basis, with the ability to show each weeks worth of records for each child. 
I am having trouble trying to figure out how to implement a table with a form like this:

```
            <- Previous Week                                         Next Week -> 
| Child   | Monday 5/6 | Tuesday 5/7 | Wednesday 5/8 | Thursday 5/9 | Friday 5/10 |
| child1  | __________ | ___________ | _____________ | ____________ | ___________ |
| child2  | __________ | ___________ | _____________ | ____________ | ___________ |
Submit
```

I currently have two models with a has_one and has_many relationship:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first, presence: true
  validates :last, presence: true
  attr_accessible :age, :first, :last, :created_at
  belongs_to :site
  has_many :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :time, :child_id
  belongs_to :child

  scope :thisweek, lambda {
    where("date between ? and ?", Date.today.at_beginning_of_week, Date.today.at_end_of_week)
  }
end
```

I also have 2 scaffold controllers for Children and Attendances and I am able to load all of the data needed for a week with queries like this:

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @site = Site.find(params[:site_id]) #using nested resources /site/1/attendances
    @children = @site.children.all
    @attendances = Attendance.thisweek.find_all_by_child_id(@children)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @attendances }
    end
  end
 end
```

Beyond this I'm stuck on how to get this data into a form like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Likert. I was building a form helper gem for this same need, however have yet to finish it.

Something like this will get you started:

```
<%= form_tag(:attendance) do %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Child </th>
        <% @dates.each do |date| %>
        <th><%= date.day %></th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @children.each do |child| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= child.name %></td>
        <%= child.attendances.thisweek.each do |attendance| %>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "children[#{child.id}][attendance][attendance.id][present]", child.attendances.present %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

@dates = however you plan to get it, maybe a distinct from @attendances.

I assume all you would need is a boolean value, present or not present, so I used check_box_tag, but feel free to adapt this to your app. This is just an example. This also assumes that the attendance for the week already exists and is associated with the children.

As stated, this is a start, you can get a good idea on how to adapt it to your needs.